# Returning the error code or message from AJAXFileUpload

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

My AjaxFileUpload control is failing for a user's upload, and I can't figure out why. I added an OnclientUploadError Javascript stub which does indeed fire--but how do I get the actual error message or code?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on a [Sample site](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit.SampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx#L63-L65), there are 2 parameters passed to an error handler - `sender` and `event (or`e`):

```
function onClientUploadError(sender, e) {
    document.getElementById('uploadCompleteInfo').innerHTML = "There was an error while uploading.";
}
```

You can check the second parameter for details of an error.